# Validation fails because validate presence not respected rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Transaction` model belongs_to 2 `UserWallet` (`sender_wallet`,`receiver_wallet`) instances.
And I validate the presence of those 2 instances, amongst other attributes `currency, amount...`
On create, I also make sure that the `sender_wallet` has enough money to create that transaction

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender_wallet, class_name: 'UserWallet'
  belongs_to :receiver_wallet, class_name: 'UserWallet'

  validates :sender_wallet, :receiver_wallet, :amount, :currency, presence: true

  validate :validate_balance, on: :create

  def validate_balance
    if sender_wallet.balance < amount
      errors.add(:amount, 'Not enough money')
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when using `belong_to` shoulda-matcher for sender_wallet, it sets the sender_wallet to nil, and calls the validate_balance which throws

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `balance' for nil:NilClass
```

Shouldn't that fail because the sender_wallet is not set?
I've tried to dig into it using the console, and when I do

```
Transaction.create(amount: 10000, currency: 'EUR')
```

it fails the same way

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

All Validations will be revoked one by one. So, as per your code, first, it will validate the presence then validate_balance.

Now, in validate_balance validation, you have the sender_wallet nil that causing this error.

Better option check for sender_wallet presence before validate_balance method by these three ways:

1. In your validation code

   ```
   validate :validate_balance, on: :create, if: -> { sender_wallet_id.present? }
   ```
2. In your validate_balance method

   ```
   def validate_balance
     if sender_wallet.present? && sender_wallet.balance < amount
        errors.add(:amount, 'Not enough money')
     end
   end
   ```
3. use try(:attribute), this won't generate the exception.

   ```
   def validate_balance   
     if sender_wallet.try(:balance) < amount
       errors.add(:amount, 'Not enough money') 
     end 
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest I don’t understand the point of validating that sender_wallet is present if I still have to check it afterwards. FYI it used to work fine in rails 4